# openssl: generate certificate request with non-DNS subject alternative names

Tags: openssl, certificate

To create a certificate request containing subject alternative names (SANs) for a host, with openssl, I can use a config file like this (snipped):

```
[req]
req_extensions = v3_req
[ v3_req ]
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
DNS = xyz.example.com
```

If I need to provide a distinguished name or a user principal name, how should I configure the `alt_names` section for a user certificate request?
For example, I tried

```
[alt_names]
UPN = xyz@example.com
```

But I got this error:

```
Error Loading request extension section v3_req
5356:error:22075075:X509 V3 routines:v2i_GENERAL_NAME_ex:unsupported option:.\crypto\x509v3\v3_alt.c:557:name=userPrincipalName
5356:error:22098080:X509 V3 routines:X509V3_EXT_nconf:error in extension:.\crypto\x509v3\v3_conf.c:93:name=subjectAltName, value=@alt_names
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can specify pretty much anything that your CA allows.

The relevant RFC is [RFC5280](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5280.txt). It says in section 4.2.1.6. "Subject Alternative Name"

> The subject alternative name extension allows identities to be bound
>      to the subject of the certificate.  These identities may be included
>      in addition to or in place of the identity in the subject field of
>      the certificate.  Defined options include an Internet electronic mail
>      address, a DNS name, an IP address, and a Uniform Resource Identifier
>      (URI).  Other options exist, including completely local definitions.
>      Multiple name forms, and multiple instances of each name form, MAY be
>      included.  Whenever such identities are to be bound into a
>      certificate, the subject alternative name (or issuer alternative
>      name) extension MUST be used; however, a DNS name MAY also be
>      represented in the subject field using the domainComponent attribute
>      as described in Section 4.1.2.4.  Note that where such names are
>      represented in the subject field implementations are not required to
>      convert them into DNS names.

You should read the rest of that section, and then check with your CA what they support. It's worth noting that your CA **must** verify that all subject alternative names are correct.

To use an email address, the RFC says in section 4.1.2.6

> Conforming implementations generating new certificates with
>      electronic mail addresses MUST use the rfc822Name in the subject
>      alternative name extension (Section 4.2.1.6) to describe such
>      identities.  Simultaneous inclusion of the emailAddress attribute in
>      the subject distinguished name to support legacy implementations is
>      deprecated but permitted.

So instead of UPI, you should use rfc822Name.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer (and for making me discover acme.com) but I actually just need to know what I should write in the openssl config file to get, for example, a UPN SAN. I edited my question to make it clearer now.

Comment: Ah, got it! Give me a minute, I'll update my answer with specific information about email.

Comment: Thanks again, that was a good idea, but actually it turn out that openssl just wants some special tags in the configuration file, which I discovered checking the source code...

Comment: I'm glad you found it!

Answer (score 19):

After trying some options (thanks Jenny) I just checked the source code, and discovered that the configuration file expects one of these values:

- email
- URI
- DNS
- RID
- IP
- dirName
- otherName

So in my case I wrote

```
[alt_names]
email = xyz@example.com
```

And openssl generated the request file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when using @alt_names that the section is `[alt_names]` and not `[alt _names]`.